# how to solve CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed. on windows

Tags: django

CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

i try to make multi language support website on django it shows error like
"CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed."